# "Install" lame on linux server with only FTP access

Tags: linux, lame

I have a linux server which I have FTP access to. Is there anyway I can call something like:

```
exec('lame dfe96adc63_o.mp3 -f -m m -b 16 --resample 8 dfe96adc63.mp3');
```

From a php script uploaded to the server (and it work)?

I'm a linux newb btw. I do everything on a Windows 7.

Comment: If your webserver is a linux one , you can execute "all" command you want. Be sure you have lame installed.

Comment: You're going to have to tie together the elements of your problem with a bit more detail. Call lame, via FTP with PHP, really?

Comment: uh... I'm going to upload a PHP script that calls exec on lame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the ftp server you are logging into allows SITE EXEC (which is highly unlikely), then there's no way to run a command like this on the remote system.